Debugging multiple python files in VS Code
I am trying to debug python files from github repository pypmu github. When I try to debug apps/pmy.py I am getting
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'synchrophasor'
  File "D:\BTP\pypmu\synchrophasor\pmu.py", line 10, in <module>
    from synchrophasor.frame import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'synchrophasor'

How can I make sure that python interprets dependent files first before debugging the active file?
I tried changing args in .vscode/launch.json  but could not figure anything out?

I don't see how this import error would be related to debugging. Looks more like a missing dependency or a bad PYTHONPATH.

I can run it properly because of hashbang "#!/usr/bin/env python3", but when debugging there is import error link : https://ibb.co/wNwjwTq

make sure that python interprets dependent files first What does that actually mean?

to make sure that modules from dependent python files(which has function and classes implementation) are loaded before active python file when debugging.

Ensure that Python modules from dependent files are loaded correctly when debugging.

Please check your launch.json to include the env setting to add your project root to the PYTHONPATH so that Python can find the synchrophasor module.

Here's an example:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Debug apps/pmy.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/pmy.py", //specifies the file you want to debug
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"  //add the workspace folder to the PYTHONPATH.
            },
            "justMyCode": false
        }
    ]
}


I assume that your project structure is as follow:
pypmu/
├── apps/
│   └── pmy.py
├── synchrophasor/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── frame.py
│   └── pmu.py
└── .vscode/
    └── launch.json


Ensure that your import statements in pmu.py and other files are consistent with the file directory structure.

from synchrophasor.frame import *

